# Why is a register initialised through bitwise operations instead of a binary string?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, programming, binary

I'm learning microcontrollers, and have picked AVRs to start with. In many AVR tutorials I find the registers are initialised by performing some bitwise operations on the assignment, for example something like this:

```
PORTD = PORTD | (1<<3);
```

There is another way to initialize that gave me the same results:

```
PORTD = 0b00001000;
```

I find the latter easier to think about. If the latter is easier to think about, why do programmers use the former? Is it because programmers, unlike in the example, usually deal with assigning very long or complex binary data to registers, and hence they find it difficult to assign a binary string and resort to assigning data via bitwise operations that may be easier to think about?

Comment: In many cases the compiler will translate the |= to a single bit operation on the AVR as opposed to a read/modify/write using PORTD that the code implies. Also worth noting is the (1<<3) is evaluated by the compiler - no actual code to do the bit shift is generated. [edit] I see justme said much the same thing!

Comment: As the most upvoted answer doesn't address this: your second example defines *all* bits in `PORTD` at the same time, setting bit 3 and clearing all the others. Using `1<<3` or `0b000010000` is a matter of style, but omitting the `|` changes the functionality!

Comment: @GuntramBlohm as the author of that answer: Um, yes, I do, second large heading! *Your two lines of code do different things; |= only sets the additional bits in the right hand side of the statement, = overwrites the content.*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## `0b00001000` vs `1<<3`

The binary notation is not standards-compliant C. That might just rule it out.

If it doesn't rule it out for a project: Personal preference. I do not enjoy counting twelve zeros to put something in the fourth-highest bit in a 16 bit register, for example. I'd at the very least would use four-bit-grouped binary, or hexadecimal if I wanted to write this. At that point, actually writing `1<<12` seems clearer, in any imaginable way.

(There's older compilers that might not support `0b` binary literals in C, as well.)

## `PORTB =` vs `PORTB = PORTB|`

Your two lines of code do different things; `|=` only sets the additional bits in the right hand side of the statement, `=` overwrites the content.

## Why it's bad to choose `(1<<3)` or `0b00001000`

Generally, writing

```
PORTD = PORTD | (1<<4);
```

or

```
PORTD |= (1<<4);
```

or

```
PORTD |= 0b00010000;
// or |= 0x10;
// or |= 020; 
// or however you represent that constant
```

is bad style. What does the `4` or the `0b00010000;` **mean**?
Have a header somewhere that declares a constant, e.g.

```
// myproject.h
#define BLUE_LED_PIN (1<<4)
…


// main.c
#include "myproject.h"
…
//turn on blue LED
PORTD |= BLUE_LED_PIN;
```

See how that actually tells you what you're doing?

Comment: The last paragraph is the important one!

Comment: Or indeed to isolate your port literals as well as your pin literals, you can `#define BLUE_LED_PORT PORTD` and `BLUE_LED_PORT |= BLUE_LED_PIN;`

Comment: @jonathanjo at that point, you might as well just write a function `typedef enum {RED,GREEN,BLUE} led_color; inline void turn_on_LED(led_color color) {…};`, which would arguably be cleanest, but might be inefficient if you turn on multiple LEDs per port, but don't make sure you order the port writes in a way so that the compiler can fuse these (being clever about that function accepting a bitmask nonwithstanding.

Comment: Another approach I've seen - and this requires compiler support lest you hit impdef behavior so beware - is a bitfield definition. `PORTD.bits.BLUE_LED_PIN = 1` or somesuch. (It's a right royal shame that the C spec didn't specify enough of bitfields to be able to use them for this.)

Comment: Another reason to prefer `(1<<3)` over `0b00001000` is that the documentation for microcontrollers will often specify that the bit you're setting is "bit 3", so the "3" matches the documentation. (This is not universal - some manufacturers like to number their bits from 1, so `(1<<3)` is "bit 4", and occasionally they'll be numbered in reverse *shudder*.)

Comment: "There's no reason. Personal preference." Not entirely. `0b` is (as of ISO 9899:2018) non-standard, non-portable. It might not be available or behave differently on different compilers.

Comment: @psmears If the manufacturer numbers them starting with 1, then they don't know what they are doing. If the manufacturer numbers them in reverse order MSB=0, then they don't know what they are doing (for example IBM and Power ISA documentation is numbered this way simply because their devs were incompetent).

Comment: @Lundin: I do agree that numbering with anything other than "bit *n* has value `(1<<n)`" is sub-optimal, to put it mildly. But I don't think we can say that people who use that don't know what they're doing - sometimes great engineers are constrained by external factors (e.g. having to keep the documentation consistent with previous products that were produced by less competent people). Also note that, although the question's tagged `C`, a lot of "how to program AVR" tutorials are based on the Arduino IDE - which is C++, which _does_ support the `0b....` notation (as of ISO 14882:2014).

Comment: @psmears In case of IBM/Power ISA, they've caused every single engineer using their product to get confused, read the documentation wrong or produce bugs, simply because they aren't following industry standard bit numbering. It can't be explained in any other way than that someone had a big and smelly brainfart at some point, and apparently thought that Big endian must mean that we re-order the bit numbers... which is not just inconsistent with industry standards/mathematic conventions, but also with all other Big endian CPUs from Motorola and others released before/after Power ISA.

Comment: @psmears As for Arduino and C++, I wouldn't assume that's what used unless the OP says so. Though I posted an answer with a note about the upcoming C23 which seems to bring in binary notation, and more importantly decimal separators, into C just like in C++14.

Comment: @Lundin: "inconsistent with industry standards ... others released before/after Power ISA" Alas that's not true; IBM's habit of numbering the bits wrong dates back to [mainframe/punched](http://www.edwardbosworth.com/My3121Textbook_HTM/MyText3121_Ch10_V01.htm) card times... Re C++: Yes, I wasn't suggesting to assume one thing or another, just pointing it out since lots of people (including those posting tutorials) don't realise that the Arduino stuff is based on C++, newcomers posting questions about Arduino/AVR/etc can be using C++ without even realising it.

Comment: @Lundin huh! I thought the binary literals were in c11…i was wrong!

Comment: @psmears Ok so maybe that's IBM's contribution to the Power ISA project. Because Motorola (who did all the heavy R&D on these cores) never enumerated their bits like that. Anyways this is getting widely off-topic :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller They were in C++14 and will very likely be added in C23. Decimal separators as well, which is pretty much a prerequisite feature to allow binary in the first place.

Comment: Another advantage of `1<<3` is that it is obviously a single bit. The cognitive load of scanning the whole of `0b00001000` counting the number of bits set to 1 is higher.

Comment: `Why it's bad to choose (1<<3) or 0b00001000` I disagree with your premise. I don't think it's bad style. It heavily depends on the context. -1

Comment: Sometimes constants are clearer than to (let's say) ORing multiple bits together.

Answer (score 13):

Well, the example is very poor, as for initializating the whole port after reset, either one can be used.

The point is that later on, you might want to control one bit only, and keep the state of the other pins.

There may be some registers that don't initialize to zero on reset so it depends on many things and which makes more sense in which case.

For example you can't clear bits by ORing.

And why it is so often used on AVRs is that the CPU has specific instructions for e.g. ORing and ANDing a single bit in IO register space, opcodes SBI and CBI, so controlling one bit only encodes into a single fast hardware instruction that is atomic, instead of being a non-atomic sequence of multiple instructions performing a read-modify-write sequence.

And because of this ability to set/clear single bits by the bit number instead of mask, the AVR MCU register bit names are defined with their respective bit numbers (0..7), compared to some other MCUs which define the bit with the bit mask directly.

Therefore, on an AVR platform, you tend to see these bit shifts a lot.

Comment: Yes, this is the important reason why we use the OR assignment.

Comment: Another trick on AVR MCUs is that when you have a port as a output you can flip the pin by writing a 1 onto the linked bit of the PIN register of the port (reading that register reads the port state). no knowledge of the other port pins needed for that and its one atomic instruction.

Comment: @masterX244 That is AVR specific. It is not a generic feature of all AVRs.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about the shifting, but the ORing is most useful is when the same register shares multiple unrelated functions. Then the second initialization doesn't disturb the previous initialization.

```
// Initialize function A
Reg = Reg | some_bits_to_set; 
... 
... 
// Initialize function B 
Reg = Reg | some_other_bits_to_set;
Reg = Reg & ~some_bits_to_clear 
...
```

Comment: The shifting is because in AVRs, all register bit names are defined as per their respective bit number instead of their respective bit mask. And even without that detail, if you know you want to set bit 4, then set bit 4 by shifting a 1 by 4 bits which enables compiler to use cbi/sbi instructions instead of doing a read/modify/write with the mask 0x10.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290) It answers most of the question and also explains why `1u <<` should always be used and never `1 <<`.

---

**Regarding `0b` notation**

`0b` numbers should be avoided for several reasons:

- It isn't valid C but a non-standard extensions. `0b` might not be available on specific compilers, or might behave differently between different compilers.
- It has the same signed or unsigned problem as hex constants - depending on what value you use, you get different types. Example:

  ```c
  if(~0b1 > 1)
  {
    puts("This is what I expected");
  }
  else
  {
    puts("This is what I got instead");
  }
  ```

  This is all because `u`/`U` suffix wasn't used. Check out this example:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define WHAT(x)                             \
    _Generic((x),                             \
    int:           puts("int"),               \
    unsigned int:  puts("unsigned int"),      \
    long:          puts("long"),              \
    unsigned char: puts("aint gonna happen"), \
    char:          puts("aint gonna happen")) \

  int main (void)
  {
    WHAT(0b1);
    WHAT(0b00000000000000000000000000000001);
    WHAT(0b10000000000000000000000000000000);
    WHAT(0b00000000000000000000000000000001U);
    WHAT(0b100000000000000000000000000000000);
  }
  ```

  Output from one particular gcc/GNU17 compiler:

  ```
  int
  int
  unsigned int
  unsigned int
  long
  ```

  Apart from this (hopefully) behaving like hex constants (which might already give you surprising results as seen above), it isn't well-defined either. Because standard C (C17 C17 6.4.4.1/5) explicitly specifies the behavior of integer constants when typed in decimal, octal or hex format but it does *not* specify the same for binary format. So what type you will end up with on some specific compiler is anyone's guess.
- Binary is less readable than hex. ***This is the very reason why we use hex in computer science in the first place*** - it is a more conventient way to express binary numbers.

  Sure as long as you have 8 bit registers that's not a problem, but what if you have 32 bit registers? Does `REG = 0b10010010110011001010010111110000` look like sensible code? Of course not, it's an unreadable mess and the reason why C never bothered to include a `0b` format in the first place.

  (That being said, the upcoming "C23" version of the C language looks like it will be adding `0b` notation, since it with also add decimal separators to make large numbers more readable, such as `0b1001'0010`. But neither binary constants nor decimal separators are standard C.)

---

**Regarding common bit masking coding styles**

As explained in my link and in other answers, "magic numbers" is unacceptable and we should use meaningful names such as `SPICR = SPICR_SPIE | SPICR_CPHA ;`

As for how to declare the actual bit masks, there's two acceptable forms commonly used:

```
#define SPICR_SPIE (1u << 7)  // bit number notation
```

or

```
#define SPICR_SPIE 0x80u      // raw hex notation
```

The  bit number notation is more common overall, but especially in the "Atmel world" like AVR or SAM series, Atmel/Microchip Studio and corresponding "bloat libs" like ASF. So I would recommend using it.

Comment: Whether binary is more or less readable than hex depends upon what is being represented.  If a 16-bit register uses five bits to control each of three functions, a value written as `110101101011010` may be easier to read than 0x6B5A, , especially if the previous line contains a suitably-aligned comment `-----=====-----`.

Comment: @supercat You can assume that the person reading your code is a programmer and therefore has no problem reading hex. Grouping of bits is best represented as bit masks, so your code could have been written as `#define MASK0(x) ( ((x) << 0) & 0x1Fu )` etc ... `MASK2(0x1A) | MASK1(0x1A) | MASK0(0x1A)`. No "ASCII art" needed. And whoops, with the binary goo dispelled we find out it's the same value written 3 times. And then maybe we realize it should have written as `MASK2(val) | MASK1(val) | MASK0(val)`. Yet another illustration of why binary is problematic.

Comment: I'm probably better than most people at decoding hex "on the fly", but if asked whether a number contains five or more consecutive 1 bits, I'd have an easier time answering the question if the number was written in binary than if it's written in hex.    If one is looking at code while referring to a data sheet or reference manual that includes positional diagrams of register bits, having the layout of bits in code match the layout of bits in the diagram may make things easier to read than having things written other ways.  Personally, I would have like to have seen the language spec allow...

Comment: ...implicit concatenation of numeric tokens, with the proviso that a programmer must avoid having any tokens that would match any defined macro names unless one wanted them to be expanded.  Even when using hex numbers, it's easier to proofread `0x 3000 0000 0000 0007` than `0x3000000000000007`, and such concatenation rules would eliminate the need for the PP-number concept.

Comment: @supercat As already mentioned in the answer, I consider implementing decimal separators a prerequisite to allowing binary constants, and it looks like C23 will have both. As for how many digits a number are, well luckily 99.999% of all computers ever made use a word size which is a multiple of 4 bits, so there's really no reason not to use hex in any given hardware-related scenario.

Comment: (And well C already allows `#define X 0x3000 ## 0000 ## 0000 ## 0007` but if that's more or less readable is another story.)

Comment: I've seen many hardware registers which use groups of three bits (which fits quite nicely with octal), and some that use five (which unfortunately doesn't fit well with anything).  As for token pasting, that only works in macro expansion,

Answer (score 3):

basically it's because it's a simpler operation (!)

```
PORTD = PORTD | (1<<3);
```

(here (1<<3) can be replaced with any other constant valued expression that's available at compile time and comes out to the same value)

Compiles to a single word opcode

```
sbi PORTD,3
```

(or in the general case all instances of 3 above can be replaced by a constant between 0 and 7 inclusive)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the bitwise or the constant assignment operations will be identical. If one would be more efficient than the other (but give the same ultimate result), the compiler will *change* the method to the optimal one.

Therefore the main reason for one over the other is to provide some amount of self-documentation or clarity to the code. Of course this is a matter of preference and style.

Comment: They are only equivalent if the destination is **known** to be exactly zero. Otherwise they have different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Marcus Müller's excellent answer:

In the question you say:

> There is another way to initialize that gave me the same results:

That's only true if the current value of PORTD is zero. But if PORTD is currently, say, 1, doing `PORTD = 0b00001000;` will give a different value compared to `PORTD = PORTD | (1<<3);`.

The point of writing this operation in this way to set one bit **and leave the other bits alone**. That's why we can't just assign a fixed value.

Writing the number in the form `1 << x` is a really convenient way of saying "bit x", without having to count zeroes when we type, or convert from binary to hex in our heads. Though as Marcus says in his answer, even better is not to use magic numbers in our code at all.

And for completeness, if you want to clear this bit (while leaving the other bits alone), you could write `PORTD &= ~(1 << 3);`.

Comment: Indeed, it's misleading to speak of these as 2 ways to "initialize" since only the plain assignment to a constant value is initializing at all. The | version is used because we want to set specific bits *without* initializing the entire value of the register.